# Some sprite renderers in a for loop not changing

Tags: unity

I am using `OnValidate()` to help me speed up my design process. In the code below (which is in `OnValidate()`), if strictly one enemy has a weapon and the weapon is a sword or spear I change the Sprite for all enemies (the are of type Blue). I am having two issues:

1. The sprite renderer doesn't change until I run the Application though the code is in `OnValidate()`
2. Even when I run the application, not all Sprite Renderers for enemies change. I checked the number with a Debug.Log, which prints the right number, but I consistent number of Sprite renderers don't change.

   ```
       if (enemies.Count (x => x.hasWeapon) == 1) {

       if (enemies.Count (x => x.weaponType == Enemy.WeaponType.Sword) == 1) {


           for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
               if (enemies [i].enemyType == Enemy.EnemyType.Blue) {
                   Debug.Log (enemies.Length);

                   enemies[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/greenEnemy");
               }
           }

       }


       if (enemies.Count (x => x.weaponType == Enemy.WeaponType.Spear) == 1) {

           for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
               if (enemies [i].enemyType == Enemy.EnemyType.Blue) {
                   enemies[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("Sprites/blueEnemy");
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Do you have the class tagged with [ExecuteInEditMode]?

Comment: Can you show us where you populate the enemies collection?

Comment: @Draco18s No. I just need a few functions to run in edit mode not all functions.

Comment: @DMGregory I populated enemies through the inspector in the same script

Comment: @DMGregory I am still trying to solve this issue. Any other recommendations to solving this?

Comment: Can someone please help me